# Convert msexchsecuritydescriptor property

Tags: c#, active-directory

I started off here:

- [Find out which users have Full Access on a mailbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670746/find-out-which-users-have-full-access-on-a-mailbox)

and was told to use `msexchmailboxsecuritydescriptor` AD property. I found

- [How to read msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor attribute in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231730/how-to-read-msexchmailboxsecuritydescriptor-attribute-in-c-sharp)

but this does not work, because I don't know how to provide a proper p_InputValue. I collected a securitydescriptor:

```
ResultPropertyValueCollection msexchsd = 
                       searchResult.Properties["msexchmailboxsecuritydescriptor"];
```

and then I tried to get a value:

- `ResultPropertyValueCollection p_InputValue = msexchsd;` threw an InvalidCastException from ResultPropertyValueCollection to SecurityDescriptor at runtime
- `object p_InputValue = msexchsd[0];` threw an InvalidCastException from **System.Byte[]** to SecurityDescriptor at runtime
- `byte[] p_InputValue = (byte[])(msexchsd[0]);` threw an "Implicit conversion not allowed" from byte[] to SecurityDescriptor during compile
- `String p_InputValue = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])(msexchsd[0]));` threw an "Implicit conversion not allowed" from string to SecurityDescriptor during compile

All these errors occured in this line:

```
SecurityDescriptor sd = (SecurityDescriptor) p_InputValue;
```

What can I try next? I marked the only obvious deviation: It looks to me as if the property is a System.Byte[], but what can I feed into the SecurityDescriptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

- `ResultPropertyValueCollection` cannot be converted to `SecurityDescriptor`
- `PropertyValueCollection` can be converted to `SecurityDescriptor`
- `ResultPropertyValueCollection` can be "converted" to `PropertyValueCollection` using `GetDirectoryEntry()`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a quite old question but I had to do the same thing recently and came to an other solution which I wanted to share here.

Since you want to read the full access permissions on a mailbox, here is an alternative to using the `SecurityDescriptor`:

```cs
var msexchsd = searchResult.Properties["msexchmailboxsecuritydescriptor"];

var dacl = new ActiveDirectorySecurity();
dacl.SetSecurityDescriptorBinaryForm(msexchsd);

var acls = dacl.GetAccessRules(true, false, typeof(SecurityIdentifier)); // valid target types are `NTAccount` and `SecurityIdentifier`

foreach (ActiveDirectoryAccessRule acl in acls) {
  var hasFullAccess =
    acl.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow &&
    acl.ActiveDirectoryRights.HasFlag(ActiveDirectoryRights.CreateChild);

  var targetSid = (SecurityIdentifier)acl.IdentityReference; // the cast is ok because we have asked for the the identity to be a SecurityIdentifier above
}
```

From what I have measured in my application, this solution is also a lot faster than the one using `SecurityDescriptor`, but this may depend in other use cases.