# Active Directory Shared Mailbox user permissions

Tags: c#, active-directory, exchange-server

I need to write a C# app that queries Active Directory and returns a list of users that have permission to use a certain Shared Mailbox.

I've spoken to our Support department and they say that each Shared Mailbox has an associated Security Group. And to grant a user access to a Shared Mailbox, they make the user a member of the associated Security Group.

My question is what is the link between a Shared Mailbox and a Security Group in AD? How can I work out which Security Group is associated to which Shared Mailbox?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor attribute of the Shared Mailbox object in Active Directory which will give you the DACL of the Mailbox. eg [How to read msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor attribute in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231730/how-to-read-msexchmailboxsecuritydescriptor-attribute-in-c-sharp)

> > How can I work out which Security Group is associated to which Shared Mailbox?

There is no direct way other then enumerated each DACL on each Shared Mailbox. Autodiscover will return all the Mailboxes a particular user has access to if the are automapped via the AlternativeMailbox element https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee237925(v=EXCHG.80).aspx.

Cheers
Glen

Edit See the Full assembly names you should be able to work the rest out yourself

```
                byte[] DaclByte = (Byte[])DirectoryEntry.Properties["msExchMailBoxSecurityDescriptor"][0];
                System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity adDACL = new ActiveDirectorySecurity();
                adDACL.SetSecurityDescriptorBinaryForm(DaclByte);

                System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRuleCollection aclCollection = adDACL.GetAccessRules(true, false, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
                foreach (System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRule ace in aclCollection)
                {
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for the link on how to read the msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor. But I don't know which namespace the SecurityDescriptor class lives in. I found the following link on MSDN that talks about the Security Descriptor Property Type and also shows an example that uses the SecurityDescriptor class. But doesn't indicate which assembly/namespace the SecurityDescriptor lives in. Can I please ask if you can kindly show me a C# example on how to enumerate through each DACL. Thank you. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180874(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: see Edit that's what I use both methods should work fine the other method is using the ObjectSecurity class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity(v=vs.100).aspx to read the SSDL form.

Comment: Thank you for the code example and I can now get the SecurityDescriptorBinaryForm. And loop round the AuthorizationRuleCollection items. But I don’t see any property values that tells me the Security Group the Shared Mailbox is linked to. Sorry to be a pain, but can you please tell me how I can find out which Security Group a Shared Mailbox is linked to (with a code example)? A big thank you.

Comment: If you check the ACL of the Shared Mailbox you can will get what objects have access to that Shared Mailbox (You can't tell what mailboxes a Group have access to by checking the group which is seems what your asking). You have to use the information you get from the SharedMailboxes ACL's to answer your question which means you need to check every Mailbox.

Comment: When I check the ACL of the Shared Mailbox the IdentityRefence.Value is set to S-1-5-10. Initially I thought it was a SID in AD and hopefully the SID of the Security Group. But after doing a Google search I discovered it's a Well Known SID Structure.

Comment: PRINCIPAL_SELF S-1-5-10  A placeholder in an inheritable ACE on an account object or group object in Active Directory. When the ACE is inherited, the system replaces this SID with the SID for the security principal that holds the account. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980032.aspx

Comment: You can probably guess what I'm going to ask next. How do I find the associated Security Group when the ACL IdentityRefence.Value of the Shared Mailbox is set to S-1-5-10? Many thanks

Comment: You should ignore the ACE for S-1-5-10 this if for the SECURITY_PRINCIPAL_SELF_RID (NT AUTHORITY\SELF) you will see this on every Exchange Mailbox. If your groups have be granted explicit rights to Mailboxes (eg via Add-MailboxPermissions) what you looking for is the explicit ACE's (eg IsInherited != true) . I would suggest you first run Get-MailboxPermissions to look at the DACL on the Mailboxes your trying which is what you LDAP code is going to return (eg it maybe they have just granted access to a particular folder and not the whole mailbox)

Comment: I've got the ActiveDirectorySecurity object (adDACL) for the Shared Mailbox I'm looking at and called SetSecurityDescriptorBinaryForm method. Then called the GetAccessRules method, which only filled the AuthorizationRuleCollection with 1 item. And that item has an IdentityReference.Value of S-1-5-10.

Comment: I spoke to our Infrastructure department and asked them to run the Get-MaliboxPermission PowerShell method for the same Shared Mailbox. It returned the NT AUTHORITY\SELF user and lots of other users that have permission to use the Shared Mailbox.

Comment: I also asked the Infrastructure department how they linked the Security Group to the Shared Mailbox. They said they link the Security Group in Outlook by right mouse clicking on the Shared Mailbox in the Navigation Pane and clicking the Data File Properties... menu item to display the Shared Mailbox Properties dialog. Then they select the Permissions tab and add the Shared Mailbox Security Group. I can see the Security Group listed in this dialog and it has a Custom permission level as follows. Read:FullDetails; Write:CreateItems,CreateSubfolders,EditAll; DeleteItems:None; Other:FolderVisible

Comment: The Infrastructure department said they aren't sure where these settings are stored. Could be in AD. Could be in Exchange. Where do you think these permissions settings are stored?

Comment: They will either be on the DACL of the Mailbox (use Get-MailboxPermissions) or DACL of the Mailbox Folder (Get-MailboxFolderPermissions). Why don't you just use Remote Powershell and then you can use both Get-MailboxPermission or Get-MailboxFolderPermission https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff326159%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx . Otherwise to read the Mailbox folder permission you will need to use EWS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh532558%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement.  The AD field on the mailbox account that I ended up using was **publicDelegates**:

```
mailboxDirectoryEntry.publicDelegates
```

This contains a list of distinguishedNames of userids or groups that have been granted access via Outlook delegation capabilities.

For this specific question, you could then list the members of the group(s) you obtain from publicDelegates.

Transitive membership can be obtained with the

```
member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=
```

selector on your query. (Very handy if your organization uses nested groups)